# WordPress bedrock setup MAMP PRO not working

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php, wordpress-bedrock

I am trying to setup a wordpress using bedrock and MAMP PRO.
But it simply doesn't work. Maybe there is something wrong with my mamp pro or with my .env file?

I followed the instruction on the bedrock site and this is what my .env looks like:

```
DB_NAME=adatabase
DB_USER=root
DB_PASSWORD=verysecretpassword

# Optional variables
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
# DB_PREFIX=wp_

WP_ENV=development
WP_HOME=wordpress.dev
WP_SITEURL=${WP_HOME}/wp
```

Here is what my MAMP Pro setup looks like:
[image]

As you can see my hostname is the same and I pointed the document root to the right folder as instructed on the bedrock site.

Now when I surf to "wordpress.dev" I get a blank page with the words "It works!" on it. I think this is some default mamp page?

When I surf to wordpress.dev/wp/wp-admin it says "not found"

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

My Apache config
[image]

Any help is realy very much appreciated :)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: _“Now when I surf to "wordpress.dev" […]”_ – but you did not forget to include the non-standard port, right?

Comment: @CBroe I am sorry but what do you mean? I tried surfing to wordpress.dev and wordpress.dev:8888

Comment: Well according to your configuration it should be the latter. And that gives the same result …?

Comment: @CBroe Yeah same result, it feels like wordpress.dev:8888 redirects to wordpress.dev

Comment: Do you have any additional settings on the Apache/Nginx tab? (Whichever one you’re actually using.) Do you have anything in a default .htaccess that could cause a redirect?

Comment: @CBroe I have no idea about the .htaccess it's my firs time trying to setup a wordpress thingy. I am actualy a custom php developer. I did a composer create as the bedrock documentation said and changed only the .env file

Comment: @CBroe I updated OP with my apache config (i think it's default didnt touch anything there)

Comment: Have you restarted the servers since making changes?

Comment: @PhilS yes II restarted multiple times. Every time I made changes

Comment: Perhaps `WP_HOME` should be `http://wordpress.dev:8888`